# Measuring Shannon's diffusion

Tags: cryptanalysis, entropy

Shannon's idea of diffusion is fundamental to cryptography.

Besides being a descriptive idea, is there any work on measuring or expressing it? Saying something like "System A has more diffusion than B" or "The information in bit x is diffused 1/3 into bit y, 1/3 into bit z, and the remaining third among 11 more bits".

Is there a way to evaluate the diffusion of a transform? XOR does no diffusion, Add with carry does small diffusion, and a permutation may do a lot of diffusion.

In short: Diffusion is a great idea - how can we approach it mathematically?

**UPDATE:** For instance, we should be able to quantify the diffusion done by adding with carry.  This breaks both of the suggested answers: Adding *may* update the value of *every* bit.  Modifying one bit of the input *may* modify several bits of the output.  But adding still doesn't diffuse very well.

Comment: Measuring the number of rounds a full diffusion takes is common.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to look at how many bits of the outputs are modified if you modify, say $t$ bits in the input. Actually, a function from $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\{0,1\}^m$ such that modifying $t$ bits in input modifies $m-t+1$ bits of output is said to achieve *perfect diffusion*.

Examples of functions with good diffusion are those associated with [MDS matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDS_matrix). For instance, the permutation layer of the AES is made of one such function (it is the ["mixcolumn"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_mix_columns) part of the algorithm).

Comment: It would be nice to disambiguate the definition or/and link to a reference. A small example could help. As is, we are left to guess if "modify $j$ bits" is to be taken as _exactly_ $j$ bits, or has some statistical meaning as in other usages of _diffusion_; the range of $t$; and for which $(m,n)$ _perfect diffusion_ can hold.